# How do I call my SignalR Hub from a Console app

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

How do I call my SignalR Hub from a Console app. And then the SignalR Hub would send the message to its clients?

(see image below)

[image]

Comment: What is "myConsoleApp", is it the app that's hosting the SignalR Hub, is it a separate process?

Comment: it is a console application. or a class library. but the purpose is that the source of the messages is external.

Comment: Then use a SignalR client to connect to the hub.

Answer (score 2):

Simple console example I have used to demo "chatting" between browsers and console. Note that this is using .Net (4.x) server/client not .NetCore so it may not work for you if you are using .NetCore version.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;

namespace SignalRChatConsole
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:7132/");
                IHubProxy hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");

                hub.On<string, string>("broadcastMessage", (name, message) => { Console.Write(name + ": "); Console.WriteLine(message); });
                connection.Start().Wait();
                hub.Invoke("Notify", "Console app", connection.ConnectionId);
                string msg = null;

                while ((msg = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    hub.Invoke("Send", "Console app", msg).Wait();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error" + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```